# how can possible replace percent sign within _percent_ text in mysql query

Tags: php

How to replace percent sign within _percent_ text in a MySQL query?

```
SELECT REPLACE(dp.desc, "_percent_", "%") AS desc1 FROM tablename
```

Comment: Put your `_percent_` and '%' the other way around. [The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) is *always* going to be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Close, you just have the parameters reversed:

```
select REPLACE(dp.desc, "%", "_percent_") as desc1 from tablename;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace